# Displaying dynamic views using Facelets / JSF

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I am about to commence work on a project using JSF/Facelets that shall integrate with a third party library.

This third party library contains the screen definition and it has the following API :

```
/** This method gets the screen information**/
public Screen getScreen(int screenId);

/** This method gets the first screen id **/
public int getFirstScreenId();

/** This method submits the screen with the user supplied 
    values and gets the next   screen id **/
public int submitScreen(int screenId, Map<String,Sring> keyValuePair) 
  throws ScreenValidationException;
```

The "Screen" object contains a list of controls. A "control" is an interface that has about 25 implementations
- namely LabelControl, TextBoxControl, TextAreaControl, DropDownListControl etc....

Here is an example of how the API will be used to collect data from the user:

Step 1: call getFirstScreenId() ==> This will return the id of the first screen to display to the user.

Step 2: call getScreen() using the screen id

Step 3: The Screen object returned in Step 2 has the list of controls. Display a HTML representation of the screen with all the controls (as a HTML form) to the user.

Step 4: The user has submitted the HTML form. Use the submitScreen() to submit the values.
The third party library will return the next screen id, or -1 if there are no more screens to show.

Step 5: Repeat steps 2-4 until the submitScreen() returns -1. If -1 is returned it means that the
data collection step is over, display the "thank you" page to the user.

The submitScreen() can throw a ScreenValidationException - In this case, redisplay the current screen with the
validation messages present in the ScreenValidationException object.

---

So, my question is how can I use JSF/Facelets to display the User Interface in this scenario?

I can picture that I need the following

1. a managed bean that has an action method that performs the interaction with the third party library. Although I think a servlet might be best suited for this?
2. Facelets UI templates for the 25 odd controls (textboxControl , dropdownlistControl etc....)
3. Code that loops through the controls in the "Screen" object and does something like

```
    // render the "html form start tag" , i.e, 

    for (Control control : screen.getControls()) {
        if (control instanceof LabelControl)
        {
           // render the LabelControl using the "label template"
        }
        else if (control instanceof DropDownListControl)
        {
           // render the DropDownListControl using the "dropdownlist template"
        }
        ....... }

    // render the "html form end template" , i.e,
```

I cannot picture how I can put these three together. Can someone help me?